# SAS: Constrain parameter of one level of a multi-level variable

Tags: parameters, sas, logistic-regression, multi-level, restrict

I’m generating a propensity score using logistic regression in SAS. The model predicts compliance with a quality measure. I will match patients into groups who actually complied and not complied with the measure with equal predicted probability to comply versus not comply with the measure.

One of the predictor variables has 4 levels. Three of them are predictors of complying with the measure, but by rules of the quality measure, the 4th level *defines* non-compliance and should not be used to *predict* compliance and kept out of the score.

Can I include the 4 level variable but restrict the parameter of the 4th level to zero or neutral in generating the score so that it plays no role in predicting compliance but the other 3 levels do?

Comment: Do you have this variable prior to the outcome? Will this be available in your training data for predictions for future observations? This is data leakage issue not a coding problem so I'll recommend this goes to CrossValidated instead.

Comment: Yes I have the data prior to the outcome (If by outcome you mean what the propensity score is predicting) for the training dataset. And in reality 3 levels are known prior to determining the outcome in everyday patient care. The 4th level once known defines non-compliance so cant be considered in a predictive model.

Comment: In healthcare applications propensity s ores are often used to predict whether a certain treatment is delivered. In this case 3 of the levels predict treatment, but one means absolutely you will not be treated so it is in fact the outcome and should not be in the model. I consider this a programming issue because I want to program the parameter of that level to be zero, no impact on the model. Doable?

Comment: No, I meant do you have that variable value before you know the final outcome. This isn’t just a case/control matching algorithm then? That’s what I’m familiar with. A better way to think about it may be, which information is available at a specific time point in the process - before the outcome is known otherwise you have data leakage. I usually diagram out the clinical process to help with that, identifying which variables are collected when, ie at start or at follow up etc.

Comment: Thanks Reeza. Yes we have all the levels before the final outcome is determined. The final outcome is mortality. Treatment here is full compliance with all the components of a quality measure. Treatment in this context starts precisely when all components are passed = compliance, or when any one required item is failed = non-compliance. The level that defines non-compliance is when a certain lab is not checked. It’s part of the definition of compliance, so that level fully defines “not treated.” That’s why I’ve thought to leave it out.

Comment: The other levels of that lab value all predict whether you might comply because they speak to how ill the patient is, and just checking the lab isn’t by itself enough to define compliance because there are other elements that must be completed. So it’s just this one level and why I hoped to render it neutral by constraining the parameter in the logistic regression producing the propensity score. Maybe this is just not possible in this very unusual analysis.

Comment: For that particular observation, what do you have before the 4th value? I would use that value if you have it because as stated the fourth is the same as the outcome.